# Replacing text in a file name

Tags: batch-file

What I am trying to do is replace part of a file name with my computer name.

```
@echo off
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
set host=%host:~4, -2%

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:-d /o:n /b') do call :next "%%a"
pause
GOTO:EOF
:next
set "newname=%~nx1"

set "newname=%newname:XXXX=zzzz%"


echo ren %1 "%newname%
```

When I run the above, it replaces the XXXX's with zzzz's

When I change `set "newname=%newname:XXXX=zzzz%"` to `set "newname=%newname:XXXX=%host%"`it just deletes the X's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you use delayed expansion?

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Host=%COMPUTERNAME:~4,2%"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D/ON') Do (Set "NewName=%%~nA"
    Echo Ren "%%~A" "!NewName:XXXX=%Host%!%%~xA"
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Thats what I just tried and that solved it! Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Simi-Off Topic, but do you know how I can add a path to the above code? Where the batch will look for the files?

Comment: The batch currently uses the current working directory. You could therefore insert at lines `3` and `4` something like `Set "CWD=C:\MyPath\SubDir"` followed by `CD /D "%CWD%" 2>Nul || Exit /B`. _You could even change that line `3` to `Set "CWD=%~1"` and run the batch file with a directory as a parameter. e.g `MyBatchName C:\SomePath` or `MyBatchName "C:\SomePath with Spaces"`. This would allow you to also drag and drop a directory onto the script to rename the files inside it._